# Multiple Widgets in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget

I got this code from here to add extra widgets in Wordpress. Works great, but other that repeating the process and changing the id. How can I create 5 in one go? Looking to add extra widgets for a new menu structure without using a plugin?

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Custom Widget',
        'id' => 'sidebar_widget_1',
        'description' => 'Place Your Widgets Here',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just need to have a basic loop. The for() pattern allows you to set the starting value of a variable, the maximum value it can be and how much the variable increments each time the loop is completed. You can find more on this function [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i ++) { 
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
        register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Custom Widget' . $i,
            'id' => 'sidebar_widget_' . $i,
            'description' => 'Place Your Widgets Here',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>'
        ));
    }
}
```

So `$i` starts off being equal to 1, then the code block runs, when it's done, `$i` is increased by 1 (`$i++`). It will keep doing this until `$i` is less than or equal to 5.

Comment: and just like a simple fix from @Daniel. Thank you so much works like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome, did you understand the implementation logic?

Comment: I do to some degree. although, I don't know what $i means ?

Comment: $i is a variable that increases in value each time the loop runs. I've updated the answer to explain in more detail @Whitey

Comment: I looking to apply this method to add a number of fields to one of my plugins. I can add a field to a job manger plugin, but how can I add multiplies, ie 4 applications fields? 
`code`
add_filter( 'job_manager_job_listing_data_fields', 'admin_add_application_field' );
function admin_add_application_field( $fields ) {
  $fields['_job_apply'] = array(
    'label'       => __( 'Apply Fields', 'job_manager' ),
    'type'        => 'text',
    'placeholder' => 'e.g. https://www.indeed.co.uk/redwood/job_id',
    'description' => ''
  );
  return $fields;
}
`code`

Comment: Can you create a new question for this so that replying is easier and the question stays on topic?